# Downvoted answers are shown in the beginning of the page

Tags: discussion, bug, answers, downvotes, voting

While reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call), I found downvoted and wrong answers at the beginning of the page and good, upvoted answers at the end. Also, the accepted answer is shown at the middle of the page.

Is it the algorithm's fault which shows answers or Is it differ from user to user? Shouldn't highly upvoted and accepted answers are to be shown at the beginning of the page?

Comment: Not a bug. It's entirely your choice. There are three ways to sort answers, clearly available to you as tabs at the top of the list of answers. Yours sounds like it's on "active".

Comment: @J.Steen But I think SO should show answers by votes by default instead of active

Comment: @Krupal: it does. But it remembers the last sort option you chose.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that accepted answer is not on the top, because OP accepted his own answer. When an asker accept his own answer, it's not showing firstly. So it's not a bug. You can see that in other questions too. Try to find some questions that has an answer by OP. So the default algorithm is;

```
if accepted answer is not by OP;
accepted answer
votes(high to low)

else;
votes(high to low)
```

Comment: ok I didn't notice.